# git push when many changed files

Tags: git, merge, git-commit

I wonder what is the best way to perform a commit when there are many changes in the repository

I always work with svn from the ide. I am learning to use git from console and I would like to do the following before a commit:

- see all files that are modified on the server
- I want to manually merge the files I want
- upload the changes to the repository.

I have been researching and found the following commands:

for commit my changes:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "..."
```

to download changes:

```
git fetch
```

I need  see the files that have changed, and then merge them manually

I know there

```
git rebase
```

but this is like a pull, I want something less invasive.

Sorry for my English

Comment: `git fetch` only updates your local tracking branches.  It does not update the actual branch you are working with.

Comment: yes, with git rebase update the actual branch. but I want to make a merge  less invasive

Comment: You can try `git gui`, it will show up a GUI dialog for you to pick up the files you want to commit(works on Linux, don't know about Windows).

Comment: @LotAbout  git gui is simple, I liked. Thank you.  But I still can not manually merge.

Answer (score 2):

This is the sequence I use:

See which files changed with

> git status

Review the changes made

> git diff

Choose which files to commit with

> git add 'filename'

Commit

> git commit -m 'Some comment'

Push the changes up to the remote repository

> git push origin 'repo'

For large or complex merging, I use NetBeans or Meld

Comment: git diff show the differences with files that are in the repository? How to merge the files manually?

Comment: I understand that using git mergetool -t meld can resolve conflicts, but I want to make a merge manually because not necessarily have to lead to conflict.

Comment: You can use the diff to show you which lines to change and use an editor on the affected file.

Comment: Thank you, But this compares stage with working directory?  I want to compare with the repository and I want to do manually merging